# IndexError: list index out of range in simple code written to find the max value

Tags: python, arrays, max

Here is my code:

```
num = int(input())
value = []

i = 0
maxval = 0

for x in range(num):
    value[i].append(input())
    if value[i] > maxval:
        maxval = value[i]
    i = i + 1

print(value)
```

I keep banging my head against code.  I know what it is I'm not seeing is something very simple.  Maybe even something like a misspelling?

This is for an exercise in normalizing, but I don't want to broach that step until I get over this initial hurdle.

In this exercise, there are six inputs.  The first determines the size of the array, and then from the next five inputs I need to determine the max.

The inputs are:

```
5
30.0
50.0
10.0
100.0
65.0
```

The way I read the code is: variable num is assigned 5, and it uses that to loop the next bit five times.  Variable value is the list, it's empty.  Every time the loop goes around, a new input is added to a spot in the list, starting at 0, then 1, then 2, and finally ending at 4.  Each time it goes around, maxval is checked against the latest input and if it is higher than maxval becomes that number.

But anyway, I'm getting the index out of range error, which is where I'm lost, because what it looks like to me, the first index spot is 0, which is defined already and should be available to cram inputs into.

Thanks, gang.

Comment: `value[i].append(input())` should be `value.append(input())`. There is no `value[i]` until you append to the list. Also shouldn't you be printing `maxvalue` instead of `value` at the end? Another thing to consider is if you already have the `for` variable `x` why do you need `i`? Their values will always be the same.

Comment: Ah, that is it.  I am glad the problem was that my code-grammar was off and not that I was entirely misunderstanding the concept.  Oh, and that last bit, that was related to something else I was doing and I shouldn't have included it.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build in fuction max() for that.

for every ... in range of the input number you add the number to the list.
once all the values are added you print the highest value.

```
len = int(input())
values = []

for _ in range(len):
    values.append(input())

print(max(values))
```